# Docker fails to push images to Google Cloud Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-registry

I am trying to push a Docker image to Google Cloud Registry via the GitLab ci pipeline.

The image builds but when its time to push to registry i get the following error.

> denied: Token exchange failed for project 'xxx-dev01-xxxxx'. Org
> Policy Violated: 'eu' violates constraint
> 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'

**.gitlab.yaml**

```
deploy:dev:
  allow_failure: true
  extends:
    - .prod
  stage: Deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: "eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/testapp"
  before_script:
    - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud config set project $DEV_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud auth configure-docker
    - gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io < ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
  script:
    - docker build . -t "$IMAGE_TAG" 
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG:latest
  when: manual
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to violate one of your Organisation Policy, the "resource location" one.

According to the documentation, it looks like your company is preventing you to store data into this location (region).

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations

You might want to try to change the `eu.gcr.io` with another one from this list.

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#add-registry